# Biasing Circuit for MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, pwm, mosfet-driver, biasing

I am struggling with a biasing circuit for my MOSFET. Can you help me?

It is hard to decide what kind of biasing circuit should be used. So my mind went blank. I hope the information in the picture is good enough for you.

[image: Biasing Circuit]

Answer (score 1):

The gate threshold voltage for this device is low, at most 2.5V. Given that gate potential is provided by a 0V/3.3V output from the microcontroller, there's no biasing necessary. The microcontroller is quite capable of directly driving that gate, although a small resistance between microcontroller output and MOSFET gate maybe a good idea (see below).

Maybe what you are concerned with isn't biasing, but driving. If the load you are switching is particularly heavy, fast transitions at the gate are important to keep the MOSFET from transitioning too slowly between on/off states, where it is partially conductive and dissipating power itself. The relatively weak microcontroller output may not be able to charge the gate capacitance quickly enough to achieve this, and the thing you require is a gate driver IC, or equivalent DIY solution.

Another concern is dirty loads, like motors, which can generate large transient voltages at the drain. They can get coupled to the gate via the MOSFET's internal parasitic capacitances, which puts the microcontroller at risk. This can be mitigated with a small resistance between the microcontroller's output and the transistor's gate. Again, a gate driver IC in the middle is your best solution if you think this might be an issue, since such drivers are designed to tolerate horrible conditions.

Tell us more about the load, and you'll get better answers.

Comment: "any gate potential above 2.5V will fully switch on your MOSFET" - incorrect. The threshold voltage is the point where the MOSFET starts to turn on; the datasheet specifies this at a drain current of 1mA. It doesn't even bother showing curves for Vgs less than 5V.

Comment: *Given that gate potential is provided by a 0V/3.3V output from the microcontroller, there's no biasing necessary* The output voltage depends on the supply rail tolerance and the output VOH max., which doesn't give 3.3 V. It's a significant consideration when driving a FET gate at low voltage.